# Is it safe to use firebase blaze plan?

Tags: firebase

I have very simple question, never found answer for that. When are paid costs for using blaze plan? **Do you buy some credit and firebase works till you have this credit?** What happens when credit reaches 0 and is refilled. Does firebase start to work after that immediately?

Or do you pay after every month, based on what was used? This could bring very unpleasant surprises if you make coding mistake or become target of some hacker. One can sacrifice 100$ in credit but probably not 100000$ for some infinite loop uploading files for whole month...

Comment: Have you seen this? https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Maybe this one helps, but you have to implement it yourself ... https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#cap_disable_billing_to_stop_usage

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Firebase Blaze plan is a "pay as you go" plan, as indicated on the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/). It is a post-billing service, meaning that you get billed for your usage at the end of the month.

During the month, you can track your usage (and thus pricing) for the service in the Firebase Console.

If you ever get a bill for an exponentially unexpected rate, [reach out to Firebase's billing team](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/account-services/) who will work with you to investigate the cause.

---

If you're actively developing your code or are likely to make changes that result in infinite reads or similar operations, I'd recommend running and testing the code with the [emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) to prevent racking up unexpected charges.

---

There **is** an example of [disabling billing to stop usage](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#cap_disable_billing_to_stop_usage) when a certain condition is hit, but it's pretty involved and comes with this warning:

> This example removes Cloud Billing from your project, shutting down all resources. Resources might not shut down gracefully, and might be irretrievably deleted.

Comment: Thank you for information. It sounds scaring that there could ever occur bill that could cause huge troubles to the programmer.

Comment: Not sure it deserves new question. What would happen and in what speed if for example one used firebase functions to generate uploaded image thumbnail as in firecast video and forgot to include the code testing if the image isn't already thumbnail? That would generate typical infinite situation I am concerned about and that's reason why I ask. As with unlimited scalable storage and speed it could just create unlimited debt overnight. That's what I meant by question, what is the limit for various cases like that and what assurances programmers have even if it is fault completely on their side?

Comment: Each situation is different. If you find yourself in that situation [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help.

Comment: @hoacin I have the same concern. So what I'm planning to do is get a new credit card with the lowest possible credit limit specifically for firebase. That way, although there is no way of capping the usage from firebase, I'm capping the credit limit.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What would be your answer after the recent announcement that there is no free plan which supports cloud functions? There will still be bugs during development and w/o the security of a hard quota this might be a show stopper for most developers.

Comment: You're right, that option disappeared. These days I'd recommend developing as much as possible against the emulators, which are not affected by billing at all.

Comment: @Soropromo I believe that this is the best solution today. Leave a low limit credit card for your Google Cloud Platform account.

Comment: But then also you owe to google. And even Firebase can suspend you're account even all google account. Sounds bad . Feature request : bring flame plan back or option for setting thresholds like AWS does. Otherwise we developers either never able to enable billing or will stick to the console for whole year. Even a simple mistake from client side can make our startup die. We cannot check our emails for budgets alerts 24/7. Is there any work going on for billing limit or usage limit