# Confusion with pay as you go pricing and free pricing in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I was learning React and wanted to set up Firebase as backend. The confusion I faced was that pay you go and free pricing versions are separate, that is, free version is best appropriate for experimental projects but the question is Can I set up the pricing like this, so firstly use free pricing and once the limitations of free pricing exceeds, switch to paid version. Is that possible? because I am just not sure that if my project succeeds))

Comment: @GuyIncognito, :), no I wanted to say, is it possible to use initially free plan then on the exceed of free plan limitations start paying?

Comment: @GuyIncognito, ))), ok I just thought Google make me pay right away as it is the case with other services, that is, they ask you money first then you can use their services thus I was a bit confused))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At any moment you can upgrade your free project to a paid project. And similarly, at any moment you can downgrade your paid project back to being a free project.

On the paid plan, most services have a free quota that is the same as you'd have on a free project. In other words: if you switch to a paid plan, but stay under the free quota, you'll pay nothing.

Also see:

- the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) on the Firebase web site
- the [pricing FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#pricing) on the Firebase web site
- [Is it safe to use firebase blaze plan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622607/is-it-safe-to-use-firebase-blaze-plan)
- [Switch from spark to pay as you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926107/switch-from-spark-to-pay-as-you-go)